# Specify authentication database in mongoid.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, database

I'm trying to authenticate through mongoid.yml, but the user I want to authenticate as is in the admin database. If I try to specify the admin database in the database field, it will put all the collections in there too and I don't want that.

Is there a way to set my database field to a database I want, but specify a separate authentication database?
Heres my mongoid.yml file at the moment

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: XC_DEV
      hosts:
        - IP:PORT
      username: user
      password: password
```

Answer (score 23):

The question is over a year old but it deserves an answer.

Yes, the *auth_source* option specifies the authentication database. You got to be on mongoid 5.0.0 or higher ([documentation on the mongodb website](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config) ). Note mongoid defaults to the the admin database.

Can't find such an option for the [Mongoid 4 configuration](http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html). I created authentications on the actual databases (there could be a way I am not aware of).

Segment of mongoid.yml (5.0.0):

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_name
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        # The name of the user for authentication.
        user: "<%= Rails.application.secrets.mongoid['user'] %>"
        # The password of the user for authentication.
        password: "<%= Rails.application.secrets.mongoid['password'] %>"
        # The user's database roles.
        roles:
          - 'dbOwner'
        # Change the default authentication mechanism. Valid options are: :scram,
        # :mongodb_cr, :mongodb_x509, and :plain. (default on 3.0 is :scram, default
        # on 2.4 and 2.6 is :plain)
        # auth_mech: :scram
        # The database or source to authenticate the user against. (default: admin)
        auth_source: admin
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as the solution since the problem is solved using the proposed solution

Comment: A [link](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) to Mongoid 4 docs.